# Unexpected end of input on line 1

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've looked through all the answers on SO to find out the issue here, but nothing seems to be working. This section of my code is what throws the error (it runs fine with no errors with everything else but this bit included)

```
var code_got = getUrlParameter('code');
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: 'testing.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      code_got: code_got,
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var list_data = JSON.parse(data);
      var dataset = list_data['data'];
      $.each(dataset, function(i, data) {
        $('#your_key').append(data['name'] + ':  ' + data['stats']['member_count'] + ' customers<br>');
        $('#first_select').append("<option value='" + data['id'] + "'>" + data['name'] + "</option>");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I've tried JSLint is telling me the issue is this: "Expected an identifier and instead saw '}'." referring to this line: `code_got: code_got,`

I have several other AJAX calls structured exactly like this one that run fine. Can you spot the issue here?

Comment: wheres code_got defined?

Comment: @joyBlanks just added it in my question

Comment: Can you post what `code_got` is?

Comment: there is an extra " ," after code_got

Comment: @litelite That's allowed.

Comment: actually some browsers go crazy so yes remove the extra , and let us know if that fixed the issue. Someone added this as an answer. please accept if that works

Comment: jslint warns about it because of compatibility with old browsers, but it shouldn't cause a problem in a modern browser.

Comment: @joyBlanks Removed that comma and there was no difference.

Comment: Are you getting an error in the browser's Javascript console?

Comment: Of note, this code has worked before, but isn't working now. I've rolled back all of the changes that I've made after the fact, but can't figure out the issue.

Comment: @Barmar Yes. "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" and referring to line 1.

Comment: That probably means you don't have balanced braces and parentheses in the whole code.

Comment: @Barmar I've been through every brace and paren and they all match (as far as I can tell)

Comment: It could also be that `data` is empty, and you're getting the error from `JSON.parse`.